# Prevent term ending in an underscore from appearing as hyperlink in Sphinx docs

Tags: python-sphinx, restructuredtext

I have a class method with an argument that ends in an underscore, `from_`, and I am using `autoclass` to generate the documentation for the class. I want the argument `from_` to appear as normal text in my Sphinx documentation, but currently it appears as a hyperlink.

Here is a simplified version of the class method with the docstring:

```
class Twilio:

    def get_messages(to=None, from_=None):
        """
        Get messages.

        `Args:`
            to: str
                Receiver.
            from_: str
                Sender.
        `Returns:`
            Messages: dict
        """
        return fetch_messages(to=to, from_=from_)
```

And I am generating the documentation for this class using:

```
.. autoclass :: Twilio
   :inherited-members:
```

The problem can be seen in the `get_messages` function at the very bottom of this [page](https://move-coop.github.io/parsons/html/twilio.html), you can see that it is formatted as a hyperlink.

Comment: Please post your reST markup. Until then, you could make it an inline literal by enclosing it with double backticks "`".

Comment: Sorry about that, I added clarifying code, and also a link to the online documentation where you can currently see the bug in the function at the very bottom.

Comment: That's still not enough information. We need the complete docstring of your method and the method itself.

Comment: Okay, my apologies, thanks for your patience. Hopefully what I just added is sufficient.

Answer (score 5):

Use a backslash to escape the underscore.

```
from\_: str
     Sender.
```

Reference: https://docutils.sourceforge.io/docs/ref/rst/restructuredtext.html#escaping-mechanism